# Dido's problem with a length constraint greater than circle arclength

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I had some trouble trying to come up with a solution. Consider this
$$\int_{0}^{4}\sqrt{1+(y')^2}dx=16$$ you want to find $y$ to maximize this integral $$\int_0^4ydx$$
with $y(4)=y(0)=0$.

What I did is plug both in the euler lagrange equation to get 
$$\lambda \frac{d}{dx}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}=1$$
Which is a simple differential equation that'll get you the answer of $$y=\sqrt{4-(2-x)^2}.$$
However this has an arclength of $$2\pi$$ which is less than 16 and thereby not my desired solution. Any suggestions in getting a $y(x)$ that can satisfy the arclength of 16 and $y(4)=y(0)=0$ will be appreciated.

Comment: Why should there be a solution with that arc length?

Comment: Is there a solution?

Comment: Not with y as a C2 function of x, no. The solution wants to be part of a circle but it can't.

Comment: I see. Would I have to use another version of the euler lagrange equation if this is the case?

Comment: If you want the circle solution, use polar coordinates

Comment: I Found some integration constants but the calculations are huge. It seems y at 0 is not zero, so isn't it simply the half circle surmounting a rectangle that is easy to compute via the lacking arclength ?

Comment: Add : for the upper bound 2 : $y(x,\lambda)=\lambda C-\sqrt{\lambda^2-(x+D)}$. C,D are constants. This has now to be plugged in the equation and derivated towards lambda, it should give a relationship between lambda(the radius) and C,D.